# containeranalysis.occurrences.get denied for project XXX when using service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are attempting to use GCR's container analysis api to send notifications via pub/sub when a image vulnerability has been found.  We were able to get this working fine with a full admin account but have been unable to get a service account working.

We've confirmed the service account has full access to the Container Analysis API in the dashboard however any request we make gets denied. Our error occurs specifically when we call `containerClient.GetOccurrence` in the golang library.

Is there a special permission that needs to be granted at the project level for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to answer my own question..

The service account in question was missing the roles/containeranalysis.occurrences.viewer role in IAM.